# Node.js segfault - What does the stacktrace mean?

Tags: node.js, v8

I've got a node (version: v0.10.28) server running which stops from time to time without an exception.

The kern.log (linux debian) shows this errors:

```
May 28 05:01:20 pro1739 kernel: [29083831.961652] node[32519]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff520fa478 error 14 in node[400000+80d000]
May 28 05:41:29 pro1739 kernel: [29086239.406993] node[1893] general protection ip:7c9334 sp:7fffc7644440 error:0 in node[400000+80d000]
May 28 05:50:45 pro1739 kernel: [29086794.741280] node[4227]: segfault at 7000000000b ip 00000000007c9334 sp 00007fff49b6d9b0 error 4 in node[400000+80d000]
May 28 06:26:27 pro1739 kernel: [29088936.031535] node[4732]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffe25a9978 error 14 in node[400000+80d000]
May 28 07:02:48 pro1739 kernel: [29091115.229410] node[6904]: segfault at 700000007 ip 00000000007bdd0d sp 00007fff7d722160 error 4 in node[400000+80d000]
May 28 08:00:58 pro1739 kernel: [29094603.815258] node[8970]: segfault at 40000000b ip 00000000007c9334 sp 00007fff457b8950 error 4 in node[400000+80d000]
May 28 08:37:27 pro1739 kernel: [29096791.454732] node[12482] general protection ip:7c8edf sp:7fff612a5ab0 error:0 in node[400000+80d000]
May 28 10:37:41 pro1739 kernel: [29104001.982760] node[14603]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffcb7ace18 error 14 in node[400000+80d000]
```

I managed to take a stacktrace:

```
PID 22101 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x7
/home/nodejs/node_modules/segvhandler/build/Release/segvhandler.node(+0x2fcd)[0x7fe355d98fcd]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf030)[0x7fe356538030]
/home/nodejs/.nvm/v0.10.28/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal18IncrementalMarking4StepElNS1_16CompletionActionE+0x2e4)[0x681fa4]
/home/nodejs/.nvm/v0.10.28/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8NewSpace15SlowAllocateRawEi+0x71)[0x774e31]
/home/nodejs/.nvm/v0.10.28/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal4Heap8AllocateEPNS0_3MapENS0_15AllocationSpaceE+0x1e8)[0x621c08]
/home/nodejs/.nvm/v0.10.28/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal4Heap23AllocateJSObjectFromMapEPNS0_3MapENS0_13PretenureFlagE+0x56)[0x624c96]
/home/nodejs/.nvm/v0.10.28/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal4Heap27AllocateJSArrayWithElementsEPNS0_14FixedArrayBaseENS0_12ElementsKindENS0_13PretenureFlagE+0x20)[0x624da0]
/home/nodejs/.nvm/v0.10.28/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal7Factory22NewJSArrayWithElementsENS0_6HandleINS0_14FixedArrayBaseEEENS0_12ElementsKindENS0_13PretenureFlagE+0x37)[0x6051e7]
/home/nodejs/.nvm/v0.10.28/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal19Runtime_StringMatchENS0_9ArgumentsEPNS0_7IsolateE+0x3dd)[0x75279d]
[0x3e9691a06362]
```

Could somebody help me with that stacktrace ?
For me it looks like node's trying to allocate heap memory for an array?

Thank you!